# npm install returns connection timeout while building docker image

Tags: docker, npm, node-modules, npm-install

I am trying to make a docker image including `newman`. I tried to build the image using `node:10-alpine`, but I got connection refused error while `npm install -g newman`. This is my docker command:

```
RUN set http_proxy= && \
    set https_proxy= && \
    yarn config delete proxy && \
    npm config rm https-proxy && \
    npm config rm proxy && \
    npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/ && \
    npm config set strict-ssl false && \
    npm cache clean --force && \
    npm cache verify && \
    npm install -g newman
```

The full error is:

```
npm ERR! code ECONNREFUSED
npm ERR! errno ECONNREFUSED
npm ERR! FetchError: request to https://registry.npmjs.org/newman failed, reason: connect ECONNREFUSED 192.168.14.109:1087
npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.req.on.err (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-fetch-npm/src/index.js:68:14)
npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:198:13)
npm ERR!     at onerror (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/agent-base/index.js:101:9)
npm ERR!     at callbackError (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/agent-base/index.js:123:5)
npm ERR!     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
npm ERR!  { FetchError: request to https://registry.npmjs.org/newman failed, reason: connect ECONNREFUSED 192.168.14.109:1087
npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.req.on.err (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-fetch-npm/src/index.js:68:14)
npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:198:13)
npm ERR!     at onerror (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/agent-base/index.js:101:9)
npm ERR!     at callbackError (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/agent-base/index.js:123:5)
npm ERR!     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
npm ERR!   message:
npm ERR!    'request to https://registry.npmjs.org/newman failed, reason: connect ECONNREFUSED 192.168.14.109:1087',
npm ERR!   type: 'system',
npm ERR!   errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
npm ERR!   code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
npm ERR!   stack:
npm ERR!    'FetchError: request to https://registry.npmjs.org/newman failed, reason: connect ECONNREFUSED 192.168.14.109:1087\n    at ClientRequest.req.on.err (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-fetch-npm/src/index.js:68:14)\n    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:198:13)\n    at onerror (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/agent-base/index.js:101:9)\n    at callbackError (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/agent-base/index.js:123:5)\n    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)' }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2020-03-02T14_57_46_444Z-debug.log
```

Then I tried to make my image from `alpine:3.8` which gives me repository error while `apk update`. This is my second version:

```
RUN apk update && apk add --no-cache nodejs npm
RUN npm install -g newman
```

Full error log is:

```
Step 5/7 : RUN apk update && apk add --no-cache nodejs npm
 ---> Running in 6149b2571389
fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.8/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
ERROR: http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.8/main: operation timed out
WARNING: Ignoring APKINDEX.adfa7ceb.tar.gz: No such file or directory
fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.8/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
ERROR: http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.8/community: operation timed out
WARNING: Ignoring APKINDEX.efaa1f73.tar.gz: No such file or directory
2 errors; 13 distinct packages available
The command '/bin/sh -c apk update && apk add --no-cache nodejs npm' returned a non-zero code: 2
```

I also tried to build the image with `--network=host`option; but got the same errors in both versions.

Additionally `ping dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org` works fine on my system.

Besides, restarted the docker service, `sudo systemctl restart docker`, and tried one more time. Got the same results again.

Answer (score 2):

In my case works with this steps:

1. In the Host, I change Host Server
   /etc/sysctl.conf:

I added

```
net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
```

2. I use

   nslookup registry.npmjs.org

Give me the IP 104.16.25.38

3. Docker Build with IP

> docker build . --add-host registry.npmjs.org:104.16.25.38 -t test

Comment: It seems it doesn't get to the `add nodejs` point. It fails while updating the `apk` repositories. BTW, I have tried your solution and it didn't work for me; I got the same error.

Answer (score 1):

In my case works with this below **single** step,

**docker build --add-host registry.npmjs.org:104.16.25.38 -t  .**

Comment: It is exactly the same as @Hernaldo suggested previously. Please read my comment under his answer.